# Dynamic facebook like button on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, url

When I use PHP to parse current URL into `data-href` attribute , the widget breaks and does not render.
Console says its because of empty string parsed into getElementById on the fb script.

Documentation says if i omit the `data-href` altogether , it defaults to current URL.
When I do that it still doesn't render , only when i predefine some static URL.

I am putting this widget into a "footer.php" that gets included after content on every page.

Is this not working for me on my dev server , because the URL is actually `localhost` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar problem (with a FB share button, though).

The only answer I can give is: Facebook does not seem to accept `localhost` in the `data-href` attribute. For me it works with anything else - e.g. with `127.0.0.1` :) .

Smells like you need to use a work-around :-/.